# Obj-C: using mutable and returning non mutable classes in methods

Tags: objective-c, collections, nsmutablearray

In objective-C I find myself creating alot of Mutable objects and then returning them as non mutable objects. Is the way I am doing it here, simply returning the `NSMutableSet` as an `NSSet` a good practice? I was thinking maybe I should specify that i make a copy of it.

```
/**  Returns all the names of the variables used in a given
 *   program. If non are used it returns nil */
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableSet* variablesUsed = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSString *str in program)
        {
            if ([str isEqual:@"x"] || [str isEqual:@"y"] || [str isEqual:@"a"] || [str isEqual:@"b"])
                [variablesUsed addObject:str];
        }
    }
    if ([variablesUsed count] > 0) {
        return variablesUsed;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning a copy make more sense, that set is complete and won't be modified anymore.

Comment: @TerenceYan No, it doesn't. If a function returns `NSSet *` and it's documented to return `NSSet *`, then one shall never attempt to mutate it. Copying just wastes RAM and CPU time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144274/is-it-good-practice-to-convert-return-value-type-from-nsmutablearray-to-nsarray/12144379#12144379

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much safety you require. If you return the object as an NSSet it will still be an NSMutableSet, so it could easily be cast back to one and modified.

Certainly, if you're creating a public API, I'd recommend returning a copy. For in internal project, perhaps the method signature already makes the intention clear enough.

Its, worth noting that, generally the performance impact of returning a copy is negligible - copying an immutable instance is effectively free whereas each copy sent to a mutable-passing-as-immutable will create another copy. So I would say its good practice to default to.

Comment: I agree for a public API´s this makes sense. Unless dealing with very big objects maybe.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Unless documented, one should never try to modify an immutable object. That's "safe enough".

Comment: The object itself is mutable.

Comment: @H2CO3: If you're disagreeing only on performance grounds, its worth noting that the non-mutable versions of core classes tend to perform better and use less ram, since they don't have to deal with the mutability concern.

Comment: As well, copying an immutable instance is effectively free whereas each `copy` sent to a mutable-passing-as-immutable will create another copy.

Comment: @bbum Thanks - suspected it was implemented like that under the hood. Nice to get confirmation from an expert. Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would do it this way.

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program
{
    NSSet *variablesUsed;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF = 'x' or SELF = 'y' or SELF = 'z'"];
      variablesUsed = [NSSet setWithArray:[program filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];  
    }
    int count;
    return (count = [variablesUsed count]) > 0 ? variablesUsed : nil;
}
```

I find using predicate to filter array quite comprehensive and easy. Rather than dealing with creating a new mutable type and then testing certain condition, adding until the loop; in this scenario, it seems to be easier to use predicate. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is an absolutely correct OOP approach (it takes advantage of polymorphism). Every `NSMutableSet` is a proper `NSSet`. Don't copy superfluously.

Comment: That's true, but if you absolutely need that this object doesn't have to be modified (maybe because it may cause your class to be in an inconsistent state), then you need to return a copy, though it's not the case of the OP.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri If the user uses the return value in an undocumented way, then the invoked undefined behavior may cause inconsistency anyway. Copying is really absolutely, 100% unnecessary.

Comment: Don't avoid copying for the sake of performance, unless you've benchmarked it and you are indeed losing time or space -- premature optimization and all that. Many Cocoa classes are optimized for fast copies, particularly when creating immutable objects.

Comment: Isn't the case of the OP, but in some cases you may need to return a copy. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer here, consider NSProxy's one, but I want to clarify something.

In your case you create your object from scratch, and you don't set any ivar to point to that object. In my opinion in a good percentage of cases you don't need to make a copy of the mutable object returned. But if there is a good reason to deny the class client from mutating the class, then you should copy the variable.

Consider a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSSet* set;
```

The class client could do this:

```
NSMutableSet* set= ... ; // inizialized to some value
classInstance.set= set;
// Mutate the set
```

Once mutated the set it could make the class be in an inconsistent state.

That's why when I have a property with the type of a class that has also a mutable version, I always put copy instead of assign in the property.